# C variable usage in assembly, how to choose 32bit operands in arm aarch64

Tags: c, gcc, arm, inline-assembly, arm64

I am trying to use C variables in assembly. The purpose is to read a 32bit memory and assign it to a C variable.

```
uint32_t ASMRegRd32(uint32_t addr) {

uint32_t data;

    asm volatile (

        "ldr %0, [%1]"          "\n"

        : "=r" (data)

        : "r"(addr)

          );

return data;

}
```

Sadly being on AARCH64, above `ldr` instruction is returning a 64bit value, as compiler is choosing a 64bit operand Xt.

How can I restrict it to use a 32bit operand?
Should this work?

```
ldr w0, [%1];

mov %0, w0;
```

Comment: Do you mean `ldr %w0, [%1]`?  Because it looks like you are trying to use the [x86 Operand Modifiers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#x86Operandmodifiers).  I don't speak aarch64 (at all), but I'm pretty sure the x86 modifiers won't work here.  If you do (speak aarch64 assembler), you might try browsing the actual [gcc code](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/branches/gcc-4_9-branch/gcc/config/aarch64/aarch64.c?revision=224524&view=markup#l3474) for constraints.  Perhaps you'll see something there you can use.

Comment: You need to write `%w0` instead of just `%0` to get `w0` instead of `x0`. Clang was supposed to get a warning to tell

Comment: Yes I meant %w0. and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You use the constraint template modifier "w".

```
asm (
    "ldr %w[DST],[%[SRC]]" "\n"
    : [DST] "=r" (data) // 32 bit variable
    : [SRC] "X" (addr) // source address variable (expands into a x register)
    : "memory"   // the compiler doesn't assume that pointed-to memory is also an input unless we tell it
);
```

See also [How can I indicate that the memory *pointed* to by an inline ASM argument may be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56432259/how-can-i-indicate-that-the-memory-pointed-to-by-an-inline-asm-argument-may-be) for ways to avoid the `"memory"` clobber, like using an `"m"(*addr)` input to get the compiler to pick an addressing mode.

Comment: +1 yes apparently an operand modifier is needed because `uint32_t` picks a 64-bit register!?! (https://godbolt.org/z/h3gXGF), but this is still missing anything to tell the compiler that the memory pointed to by `addr` is an input, as well as the pointer value itself.  Either a `"memory"` clobber, or a memory source operand like `"m"(*addr)`.  Otherwise dead-store elimination could remove a store that updates that memory before the inline asm reads it.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should change your API like below if you don't want to recompile the code in A32 compiler.

```
uint32_t ASMRegRd32(uint64_t addr) {

uint32_t data;

asm volatile (
    "ldrh w0, [%1]\n"
    : "=&r" (data)
    : "r"(addr)
    : "cc"
      );

return data;

}
```

because the default register is 64-bit, so the var addr conversion from 64-bit to 32-bit will make the program core dump.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Because ARM return value always store in the register x0/w0.

Comment: You are somehow relying on the fact that the register allocator is likely to assign x0 to data in the inline asm. That might work in some cases, but it is way too fragile.

Comment: Went with "%w0", As I'll have to push/pop w0 to stack before using this API, that is like 200% extra code for me.
Thanks

Comment: **This answer is wrong** in several ways.  First, as noted, it is unsafe to assume `w0` will be allocated.  Second, `ldrh` does a 16-bit load, not 32-bit.